# Is there a possibility to skip the finally block and continue with the rest code

Tags: java

I tried with `System.exit(0)` but that neither executes the `finally` block nor rest code.

Also tried `return` that will execute `finally` block but not the rest code

```
private static void testMethod() {
    try {
        System.out.println("try Block");
        // Skip Finally Block.
        //return; 
        // System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("catch Block");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Finally Block");
    }
    System.out.println("After Finally Block.");
}
```

Output should be

```
try Block
After Finally Block.
```

OR

```
try Block
catch Block
After Finally Block.
```

Comment: If you're asking a Java-specific question, why add the C++ tag? Spamming unrelated tags will not make you any friends around here.

Comment: As for your problem, I assume the (real) problem is with code you're not allowd or can modify? Or else the simple solution would be just to remove the `finally` block.

Comment: The whole point of the finally block is that it will always run. So you can't skip it unless you force quit your program.

Comment: If you want this, then you shouldn't be using a finally-block.

Comment: just remove the finally block.- since you are apparently able to change the code (added return or System.exit)

Comment: You could change System.out so it doesn't print "Finally block"

Answer (score 7):

You can't prevent the code in the `finally` block from running; that's what the `finally` block is for.

You *can* set a flag and use it in an `if` around the code in the `finally` block:

```
private static void testMethod() {
    boolean skip = false;
    try {
        System.out.println("try Block");
        // Point A
        skip = true;
        // Point B
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("catch Block");
    } finally {
        if (!skip) {
            System.out.println("Finally Block");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("After Finally Block.");
}
```

If code throws at Point A above, you'll see "Finally Block". If code throws at Point B above, you won't.

This is generally an anti-pattern. It's usually possible to solve real situations in a better way.

Comment: But sometimes `finally` may not get executed. [source](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/My-Tales)

Comment: E.g.. move the try/finally to the scope where you want it to apply.

Comment: @VermaAman - Heh. :-) @ Peter - Indeed. :-)